# Starting applications without aliases

Tags: command-line-interface

Whenever I install an application from a linux distro's repository I am able to then type the name of the application into the command line and it will run the application. Right now whenever I make programs or scripts I want to run conveniently from cli I will just add an alias in the .bashrc file. So while the purpose of this question is more to satisfy my own curiosity, I still would be interested in how, for example, I could run a python script from cli easily without aliasing it or resources that might point me in the right direction if it varies from os to os.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: In Linux I imagine you'd add it to your `/bin` or `/usr/bin` or anything in your path environment variable, or add the folder to the executable to your path environment variable.

Comment: Okay so let me see if I understand this correctly. If I place file foo.py in /bin I can then run 'foo' on cli and it will run the script?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [unix.se] instead, as it is not a programming related question.

Comment: @KenWhite Ah forgot that existed will take it over there possibly but I think the previous two comments have given me enough to do some further research.

Comment: Whether you post it at the other site or not, it should be deleted here, as it's off-topic for this site.